# Fastest possible retrieval from a large table with join

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have very large table (Will name it Table A : with probably 300 million records) and another table with around a 100,000 records(Will name it Table B). The task is to retrieve all the records from the Table B which is not present in Table A. The structure of both Table A and Table B is the same.

I have used Primary Key in both the tables and added Unstructured Index on the Non Unique field which is used for searching in WHERE clause.

Currently I am performing a join operation to do the task... (Col1 is the primary key)

```
SELECT Col1 FROM Table_B
WHERE Col1 NOT IN (
SELECT     Table_B.Col1 
FROM         Table_A INNER JOIN
                      Table_B ON Table_A.Col1 =   Table_A.Col1 )
```

Is there a more efficient method ?

The task is to retrieve the information within 2 minutes. But, its taking around 18-25 mins. to retrieve the same.

I am currently using LINQ to SQL with a Stored Procedure to retrieve the data. Is it beneficial or should I stick to the usual retrieval from Database.

Will it help if I decompose Table A in multiple tables using Views. But, decomposing it into views may involve complex querying. Please help me out for this problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the proper answer for it. It seems like using LINQ was not a good option. Have used it completely with parametrized SP and compartmentalized the huge Table A into multiple Tables using Views using Schemabinding. With that I have added indexes to the Primary Key field (Col1) for faster retrieval.

Now, I am able to execute it in 1 minute 4 secs time. Thanks everyone for helping me out. I have used the same join query as aforementioned for the SP

Answer (score 3):

You need to avoid "IN" statement in SQL. You can try the following

```
 SELECT Col1 FROM Table_B
 LEFT JOIN Table_A
 ON Table_B.Col1 = Table_A.Col1
 WHERE Table_A.Col1 IS NULL
```

Let me know the execution time.

Comment: For some reason, there is a huge performance drop due to this query. It took 31 minutes to execute this query. I guess the reason is the use of **LEFT JOIN**. Thanks for your nice input though.

Comment: @Kk_112688, `Table_B.Col1` and `Table_A.Col1` are primary keys? Do you have any indexes covering this JOIN columns?

Comment: @RubensFarias Yes. Both are Primary Keys

Comment: @Kk_112688 What is the DataType of the Primary keys ?

Comment: @DebajitMukherjee numeric type

Comment: @Kk_112688 - I have tested with 50 million Records in one table (Only 2 column is there though) and 100,000 records in another table (Only 2 column is there though) with Primary Key and Data Type INT.
All the queries returning results within 2 seconds. Its really wiered that in your case its taking too much time. Did you try to rebuild the indexes ?

Comment: Yea.. I did rebuild the indexes. I have 8 columns in my Table and 300 million recs. I addition, I am using through a remote server. Probably that would have been the problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this also without join

```
SELECT Col1 FROM Table_B 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table_A Table_B.Col1 = Table_A.Col1)
```

Manoj

Comment: Thanks for your input. It takes around 19 mins to execute which is same as the JOIN query. I am currently using LINQ. What's your opinion about that. And what about decomposing the table ?? Can you enlighten me in these areas ??

Comment: @Kk_112688 using an stored procedure is an option?

Comment: @RubensFarias I am currently using a stored proc. which is being called through LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to refactor the database structure and combine `Table_A` and `Table_B` into one table?  It seems like being in `Table_B` is a property of the items of `Table_A`, so rather than determining the state of an item based on what table it's in, you could add a column for `Table_B`-ness to `Table_A`